# How much more energy-efficient is it to remove the magnetic ballast for an LED tube?

Tags: led, fluorescent-lamp, ballast

The diagrams for the GE T8 tubes have these alternative  retrofit circuit diagrams:

[image: Electronic to Fuse only]

[image: Magnetic and Starter to Magnetic and Fuse]

On this website, [9W in Starter](https://reductionrevolution.com.au/products/philips-led-tube-t8), it states:

> ....with a further ~9 Watts lost in the magnetic ballast...

I have magnetic ballasts and a starter, so the retrofit does not require a rewire, but I will leave the magnetic ballast in the circuit. However, I could rewire and remove the ballast.

My question is: will it actually save 9 W, or is that loss only when a fluorescent tube is in the circuit?

I have found that the Philips installation instructions match the GE ones, but I could only found the GE circuits.

I have read this [SE.EE question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/95491/is-it-more-energy-efficient-to-remove-the-ballast-by-using-led-tube/194725#194725), but it really does not have an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A magnetic ballast is no different than a choke, so it has an inductance and a series resistance (DC resistance - DCR).

If you leave it in the circuit it'll be in series with the entire circuit. Depending on the current drawn, its DC resistance will dissipate some power.

> ...with a further ~9 Watts lost in the magnetic ballast...

This looks like an exaggeration to me. Normally, a 36W tube along with a magnetic ballast (the entire circuit), draws an RMS current of ~0.5 A when supplied from 230V grid and with no power correction at all. A dedicated magnetic ballast is usually an iron-core choke with an inductance of usually 1~1.5 Henries and a DCR of 30~40 Ohms. Now if you work out the current and DCR the real dissipation of the choke should be about 6-7 Watts. But maybe, in some circumstances, the dissipation may increase so the author of the reference might have taken those into account.

---

**EDIT:** My "~0.5 Amps" above was a crude guess from memory. The RMS current drawn by a magnetic ballast and tube network should be around **0.3 ~ 0.4 Amps** from 230 V if there's no power correction which is usually done with a parallel capacitor across the L-N.

Now, for an **uncorrected** setup, the total apparent power will be around 80-85 VA but let's be pessimistic and take 90 VA. For an uncorrected PF of 0.5, the real power will be 45 W, therefore leaving 9 W of real power dissipation to the ballast/choke if we assume the tube will dissipate 36 W *(usually they are overdriven slightly but let's be optimistic here)*. So a pessimistic approximation verifies that the ballast choke may dissipate 9 Watts, but the real numbers usually hover around 6-8 W. I also took the cold resistance of a typical 36 W magnetic ballast, so it may increase a little when hot and increase the dissipation further to approach 9 Watts.

Comment: @greybeard the cold resistance of a 36W magnetic ballast is usually around 30-40 Ohms. I don't think it'll double when hot which basically makes the dissipation ~9W.

Comment: @greybeard actually 0.3 ~ 0.4 Amps seems correct. My "0.5 A" was a crude guess from memory. With an uncorrected config the current draw should be around 0.35 Amps, making the apparent power 80~90 VA. With a power factor of, presumably, 0.5 the real power will be 45, leaving a consumption of 9W to the choke but this is a pessimistic approximation. I'm editing my answer accordingly.

Comment: @greybeard the total current reduces to 0.2 Amps with PF correction, but it's around 0.3~0.4 without any correction. The OP doesn't mention a PF correction so I assumed there wasn't any.

Comment: Thanks - the original reference of "... around 9W..." are trying to sell so they would go high - so for a fluro (AKA  low pressure discharge ) 9 W lost. None of the fittings I have inccude Caps over the ballast so there is no PF correction, as per the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

There is resistive loss in the inductor proportional to I²:
for a very raw estimate, divide by the square of the discharge current and multiply by the square of the diode operating gear's current, or the square of the current ratio.

Core losses will be reduced too - sub-quadratic, I'm afraid.

Comment: I sort of got that - but the Fluros current is (30W at 240V)  0.13 A  the LEDs (Diodes) are (10.5W at 240 V  =) 0.05 A - but what is the discharge current?

Comment: The current through the [discharge lamp](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas-discharge_lamp) - phosphorescent coating or no phosphorescent coating. I doubt 0.13 A for a 30 W low pressure discharge lamp (~1 m?); expect closer to 0.36 A. (LEDs are fluorescent lamps, too, and most white ones phosphorescent …)